# C++ ReadProcessMemory into byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, byte, readprocessmemory

I'm attempting to use ReadProcessMemory to read a dynamic amount of bytes into an array and then return it. I simply can't get it to work properly. My current code is...

```
byte *Application::readMemory(DWORD address, int length) {
    byte *buffer = new byte[length];
    SIZE_T bytesRead;
    ReadProcessMemory(piProcessInfo.hProcess, (void *)address, &buffer, length, &bytesRead);
    return buffer;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: When debugging, I get "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'buffer' was corrupted."

Comment: Is this under 32- or 64-bit Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't  it be

```
   ReadProcessMemory(piProcessInfo.hProcess, (void *)address, buffer, length, &bytesRead);
```

? If you give buffer-pointer address as input parameter, then ReadProcessMemory copies it where buffer pointer lies (not to the buffer but into buffer pointer vatiable and beyond) - and sice it is on the stack, stack gets corrupted.

Comment: I overlooked that. I just thought since I had to pass &bytesRead I would need to pass &buffer too (without realizing it was a pointer). Thanks for clearing that up.