# How can I get the value from a memory address?

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I want to get the value from a memory address which I have without crashing the program.

here is my code:

```
int main(){
    int *ptr=(int*)0x09D37570;
    while(1){
        system("cls");
        cout<<(*ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but that crashes the program, it crashes by calling *ptr, why does that happen? how can i get the value without problems?

Comment: For starters it has to be your memory.

Comment: Why does that happen? It probably happens because that memory address is not mapped at all. Where did you get it from? How do you know it's a valid address? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i got it from cheat engine, it is a real memory address

Comment: You need to use some sort of platform-specific interface that validated the address you have.

Comment: There's a difference between physical memory addresses and virtual memory addresses. You generally cannot touch memory that belongs to another process.

Comment: `ReadProcessMemory` if you're on Windows then.

Comment: @chris Interesting. I didn't even know that existed. :)

Comment: Nice chris, i think that might work, hold on

Comment: @Mysticial, It's a good possibility of how Cheat Engine works. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: @chris Make that an answer and I'll +1.

Comment: If the address is bogus / not mapped / not valid, ReadProcessMemory will return `FALSE` and not crash, but you still won't get what you wanted.

Comment: @Mysticial, I added one. I hope I didn't overlook anything important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every process has its own memory space, the same address in different processes maps different      physical address, so it is meaningless to do like that.

Answer (score 5):

You're taking a hardcoded address and expecting it to hold the value you saw. However, there are a couple problems with that:

If worrying about your own process, you have to own that memory. Something you allocate with `new` or the like had better have snatched that address, otherwise there's no telling what will happen. For example:

```
int *someAddress = new int (5);
int *somePtr = someAddress; //point to same address as newed
int someInt = *somePtr; //someInt is 5
++somePtr; //uh-oh, now we've left what we newed; it might not be allocated
someInt = *somePtr; //there's no telling if that memory was ok to use
```

If it does happen to work, you'll just get some random number. And indeed, if you loop it long enough, it will crash eventually. However, even being a problem, it doesn't even directly pertain here!

The biggest problem is that even though it has the same address, it's not the same memory. This might sound confusing, but it's a pretty great topic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Basically, each process has the same address values, but they map to different areas in actual memory. Therefore, your hardcoded address pertains to your process only.

One way you can look through other processes' memory, on Windows at least, is to use [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx). On the page, you can see the requirements, such as having the `PROCESS_VM_READ` privilege for the process you're reading from. Be sure to check `GetLastError` if it fails, too. There's somewhat of a small example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688462/c-readprocessmemory-into-byte-array).

Note that [VirtualQueryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx) is a good thing to look into before calling `ReadProcessMemory`, too.

It might work, or it might not, but it's the best thing I know of for poking around in other processes' memory space. It's worth a shot if you're set on accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, you can use `gdb` to attach to the process, and hit Ctrl-C at some point and then examine the memory. The command is `x`, so

```
x 0x09D37570
```

and you should be able to also do

```
print *(int*)0x09D37570;
```

Using `gdb`, you are in the protected memory space of the process.

What you are trying to do *does* work if there is no operating system. It *is* the correct way of getting to memory if you are developing firmware, without virtual memory address.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html